# Exception while accessing title (pytube)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

Использую библиотеку pytube. Скачиваю в плейлисте все видео по очереди и иногда появляется такая ошибка, не могу понять, с чем это может быть связано. Происходит это с разными видео и если скачивать по отдельности - все работает нормально. В интернете по запросу, упоминания такой ошибки не нашел

> pytube.exceptions.PytubeError: Exception while accessing title of https://youtube.com/watch?v=SblMnSuIFhg. Please file a bug report at https://github.com/pytube/pytube